# How to store multiple values into an array and then to DB?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am doing a billing software in C#.

I need to get and store multiple values from dataGridView into an array and then into Database.

[image: My datagridview]

[image: My table structure is]

I need to store all of those values as a single value into the "invoice" column.

I got some coding, but it not helping me.

```
string[,] invoice = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    invoice[row.Index, col.Index] = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[col.Index].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Also i have a button within the datagridview so the above code have some issues with it

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to store all which values? 10 + 15 +7? Or do you just want to represent the whole thing in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Invoice field is a varchar field you can build a string with all values and store that result:

```
 var sb = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
 {    
     sb.Append('<');
     foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
     {
            sb.Append(dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[col.Index].Value);
            sb.Append(' ');
     }
     sb.Append('>');
 }
 var toInvoiceField = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but now i need to get those values back and display them in another dataGridview... Please can you help?

Comment: No, I can't. But you're free to ask a **new** question while showing what you have tried with implementing my piece of code. You can link back to this answer